# How to clear delayed unreceived sensor data from sendbroadcast using a switch?

Tags: java, android, mobile, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app where sensor data detected on android wear are being sent to mobile through sendbroadcast. There's a switch in the mobile app to start and stop both the sensor detection on android wear and the sensor data sending process.

The problem is, there's a delay from where the data are being sent from android wear until the the data can be received on mobile using broadcastreceiver. So whenever I press the switch to stop the service and then press it again to start the process again, the mobile will continue to receive the leftover data from the previous session before it receive the data from the new session.

Is there any way I can clear all the broadcast data when clicking the stop switch, so when I press the start switch it will only receive the new data from this session?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordered boradcast :

```
void sendOrderedBroadcast (Intent intent, 
                String receiverPermission)
```

> Broadcast the given intent to all interested BroadcastReceivers,
>   delivering them one at a time to allow more preferred receivers to
>   consume the broadcast before it is delivered to less preferred
>   receivers. This call is asynchronous; it returns immediately, and you
>   will continue executing while the receivers are run.

And then you can abortBroadcat when you want :

```
void abortBroadcast ()
```

> Sets the flag indicating that this receiver should abort the current
>   broadcast; only works with broadcasts sent through
>   Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. This will prevent any other broadcast
>   receivers from receiving the broadcast. It will still call
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) of the BroadcastReceiver that the caller of
>   Context.sendOrderedBroadcast passed in.
>
> This method does not work with non-ordered broadcasts such as those
>   sent with Context.sendBroadcast